# Upload MP4 on Azure Storage ready for pseudostreaming

Tags: azure, video-streaming, azure-storage, mp4, uwp

I am building a video service application using the UWP Platform from which the users can upload and watch videos. I am using Azure Storage as the back-end.

Here is the use scenario:

- User captures a video using the [CaptureElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.captureelement.aspx) class as MP4.
- He uploads it to Azure Storage as a `video/mp4` block blob.
- Other users can watch the video using [MediaElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement(v=vs.110).aspx) class. The source is set to the .mp4 blob.

The video file is downloaded locally in order to be played by the MediaElement.

BUT, I want to make it available even when the download is not fully completed.
After a bit of research, I found [QTIndexSwapper](http://renaun.com/blog/code/qtindexswapper/), `ffmpeg -movflags faststart`  and [qt-faststart](http://notboring.org/devblog/2009/07/qt-faststartexe-binary-for-windows/) which put the metadata of the MP4 File before the data so the streaming is possible.

[Here is an MP4 video which has its metadata at start](http://portalvhdss9jyqb4ymfg54.blob.core.windows.net/freefaller/FreeFall.mp4)
[and here is one which has it at the end](http://portalvhdss9jyqb4ymfg54.blob.core.windows.net/freefaller/FreeFall_1.mp4)

The MediaElement has the same behavior as the web player.

What's the best way to achieve it in UWP app or on Azure?

Can [Smooth Streaming Client SDK Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/04423d13-3b3e-4741-a01c-1ae29e84fea6) help?

What about running a WebJob or something similar as long as the video gets uploaded on Azure Storage to move the metadata?

Thanks for your time,

George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `qt-faststart` tool from [ffmpeg repo](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/tools/qt-faststart.c). 
I created a modified version of that code as a Windows Runtime Component and used it in my project. It works perfectly.

Here is a blog post I wrote about it [Create ready to be streamed over the web videos in UWP Applications](https://uwpstories.wordpress.com/2015/08/09/create-ready-to-be-streamed-videos-in-uwp-app/)

Hope it helps someone!